# Where to locate all documents I am following

Tags: sharepoint-online

This may be a silly question but where can I locate all the documents I have clicked 'follow' on? I can easily see all the sites I am following on the front page in SharePoint but cannot locate anywhere to view the documents I am following.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be part of your OneDrive. I accessed it by clicking on the Newsfeed tile in the App Launcher waffle. There you will see your followed document count.

[image]

Click on it and it will list your follwed documents. You should end up at a URL like: https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/your_email_domain_com/Social/FollowedContent.aspx

Comment: Hi Eric, 
Thank you for your response. I do not appear to have the Newsfeed tile in my selection
Where else could this be?

Comment: Then try going directly to your OneDrive and changing the url from `/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx` to `/Social/FollowedContent.aspx`

Comment: That's worked now. Thank you. I wonder why it's hidden and the only way I can get to it is by changing the url.
Thank you though